# How to create a “find” command to find corrupted *.pages, *.key and *.numbers files?

Tags: macos, terminal

I have 3 types of files of type `*.pages`, `*.key` and `*.numbers`.

1. **Uncorrupted files:** everything Ok.
2. **Corrupted files type-I:** Where the corresponding program can display the text, but all images are lost.
3. **Corrupted files type-II:** Where the corresponding program can not open the files anymore.

I would like to make two `.txt` files, one listing the path of all the files with type-I corruption and one listing the path of all the files with type-II corruption.

I have come up with this `find` command which provides me a file *type-II.txt* with the full path of files of type-II corruption:

```
find . \( -name "*.pages" -or -name "*.numbers" -or -name "*.key" \) -and -size 102c > type-II.txt
```

And I have come up with this other `find` command provides me a file *type-I-and-II.txt* with the full path of files of type-I and type-II corruption

```
find . -type f -name "Properties.plist" > type-I-and-II.txt
```

What would be the command to be used in the terminal to provide a file *type-I.txt* listing the path of only type-I corrupted files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file in the *type-II.txt* listing is a path and file name, for example, `./document.pages`. If the same file occurs in the *type-I-and-II.txt* listing it's listed as `./document.pages/Metadata/Properties.plist`.

Use this command to create *type-I.txt* which lists files in *type-I-and-II.txt* that are not listed in *type-II.txt*:

```
sed 's|/Metadata/Properties.plist$||' type-I-and-II.txt | sort - type-II.txt | uniq -u > type-I.txt
```

The `sed` command removes "/Metadata/Properties.plist" from the file names in the *type-I-and-II.txt* listing. The output of the `sed` command is passed to the `sort` command. The `sort` command combines both files into a sorted list. The `uniq` command selects only the files that occur once in the sorted list, that is, files listed in *type-I-and-II.txt* but not in *type-II.txt*.

Comment: What is the `$` after the Properties.plist for and what has the `-` after `sort` for a function?

Comment: The `$` tells `sed` to match only the lines that ***end*** with "/Metadata/Properties.plist". The `sed` and the `sort` commands are connected by a pipe (`|`), so standard output from `sed` is standard input to `sort`. The `-` tells `sort - type-II.txt` to read standard input and the file *type-II.txt*.